# indexOf() Error on IE8 with SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

Recently, I encounter a problem when implement my web app on SharePoint with IE8.
Since the default broswer for my SharePoint is IE8 and this is unchangeable for my situration.

---

Please click the following link with my look on my flow of application

**[The flow >> Select server and date > Show figure in chart with highchart.js > Click the plot on chart > Show table with datatable.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlwHP.png)**

what my problem pop-up is when I clicked the plot of the line

1. sp.core.js?rev=7ByNlH%2BvcgRJg%2BRCctdC0w%3D%3D:2 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function(…)

Although chrome is encounter this error as well, it worked well if you ignore the error. But IE8 will stop me immediately.

What I found on google, the way of handling indexOf() in IE8 is adding following script in my HTML

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
 {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
   {
     var len = this.length >>> 0;

var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
from = (from < 0)
     ? Math.ceil(from)
     : Math.floor(from);
if (from < 0)
  from += len;

for (; from < len; from++)
{
  if (from in this &&
      this[from] === elt)
    return from;
}
return -1;
};
}
```

But where should I add? before the  or after loaded all JS library?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=BIG5;IE=8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteAssets/css/appLog/rome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteAssets/css/appLog/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteAssets/css/appLog/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SiteAssets/css/appLog/bootstrap.min1.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/jquery-1.8.min.js" charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/rome.js" charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/dataTables.responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SiteAssets/javascript/appLog/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there any way that I can do it without edit any code in the sharepoint core javascript?

Comment: `But where should I add? before the or after loaded all JS library?` - somewhere before it's required

Comment: Yeah, but the indexOf() is wirtten in sp.core.js, that's not the code wrote by me. I dont even know when sp.core.js is called. But I tried add the code before loaded library. It didnt work. Therefore, I wonder the place should I place the code. Btw, thank you for your kindly help.

Comment: make it the first js loaded then

Comment: I added a new JS called ie8.js and place it before loading any library eg: jquery. But it didnt work as expected - it changes nothing. The error message is still poped-up

Comment: can you confirm the new page is being loaded? clear cache, ctrl+f5, check the developer tools (if IE8 had such a thing)

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that the new page is loaded. But the developer tools still showing error message.

Comment: It could also be that the variable (from **variable**.indexOf) is an *object* and not a function.

Comment: Then how can we modifly the object that in other js(sp.core.js)?